# Where do I find IntelliJ settings files to import - from existing version I cannot boot (text only mode)

Tags: intellij-idea

I am setting up a laptop because my Ubuntu desktop has ended up in a state. The desktop starts in text-only mode - that is, no windowing environment.

I am starting up IntelliJ and prompted to import settings from another version of IntelliJ if I have them.

What I don't see is where that file (or what file) is stored on disk on my Ubuntu environment, and not sure if I can pick it up from the file system, move it across the network and import it into my new install of IntelliJ.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings are in s a hidden folder under your user home directory. The exact location depends on your OS and version. For further details, see: [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).